# error in defining data path to the asset folder android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

Trying to implement ocr in android app , used the tut here http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ for ocr and another for surfaceview camera integration and trying to integrate them both . Having multiple issues one of the issue i am unable to resolve is passing the file path in the asset folder to the base uri method .

here is the code :

```
protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init("file:///android_asset/tessdata/", lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();

        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }

        // Cycle done.
    }
```

and here is the logcat output

```
07-10 11:19:35.943: W/dalvikvm(24471): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab8228)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:215)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at com.example.cardboost.Home$4.onPictureTaken(Home.java:191)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:692)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-10 11:19:35.943: E/AndroidRuntime(24471):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 11:21:38.263: W/ActivityThread(24753): Application com.example.cardboost is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-10 11:24:38.949: W/jdwp(24753): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

any help would be much appreciated Thank you .

Comment: do you have folder `testdata` in assests folder?

Comment: yes i have a folder by the name of **tessdata** in the assets and it contains eng.traineddata file along with some other cube files

Comment: refer this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html

Comment: @Dixit Patel i have tried it but `  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
     baseApi.init(assetManager.list("tessdata").toString(), lang);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
     ` but assetManager.list would contain the whole data of of the list .. i just need a path to send like i tried file:///android_asset/tessdata/ ..

Comment: it does not cause any problem if i use baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/CardBoost/", lang); i have also tried baseApi.init("file:///android_asset/", lang); but that does not help aswell

Comment: Did you resolve the issue or did you have to copy the file into your sd card?